# Pivot items with caliburn.micro

Tags: windows-phone-7, caliburn.micro

I am trying to use the caliburn.micro Conductor. According to the docs, a Conductor doesn't necessarily need to be of type Screen, it can actually be any POCO.

So I create my class like this:

```
public class StoreContentsViewModel : Conductor<MyItem>.Collection.OneActive
{
    protected override void OnInitialize()
    {            
        ...
        foreach (MyItem item in Collection)
        {
            Items.Add(item);
        }            
        ActivateItem(Items[0]);
    }
}
```

but I get a binding error

```
 System.Windows.Data Error: BindingExpression path error: 'Items' property not
 found on 'MyItem' (HashCode=107597610). BindingExpression: Path='Items' 
 DataItem='MyItem'  HashCode=107597610); target element is 
 Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Pivot' (Name='Items'); target property is 
 ItemsSource' (type 'System.Collections.IEnumerable')..
```

I thought that it was Conductor the class that implements Items list, but caliburn is trying to bind MyItem. Why is that?
I want to have a Pivot, which receives a list of MyItem in the bindable property Items, and displays them according to an ItemTemplate I defined. Do I need a ViewModel for this??
I've read the documentation several times but I am still lost, could you please explain me what's happening?

Comment: Could you include xaml code from which the binding is made as well ?

Comment: the binding is made via caliburn conventions, naming the pivot Items

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem!
I was setting a DataContext in the Grid that contains the Pivot, overwriting the convention DataContext which is the ViewModel. I deleted that and worked perfect.

So, it is true that you can use any POCO in a Conductor.